# Working with long lists of bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, low-level

I am quite unfamiliar with operating on individual bits. This question is more of a sanity check than anything else:

I would like a list of, say, one million individual bits. To do this, I should create a list of `1000000/16` `unsigned ints`. Then, by iterating through these `unsigned ints` I can use bitwise operators to set the individual bits to the values I desire.

Is this correct, or am I being really dumb?
If I am on the right track, am I always guaranteed that an `unsigned int` will be 16 bits?

Comment: An `unsigned int` is not always guaranteed to be 16-bits, but on most platforms it is usually 32-bits, but also that is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no guarantee that `unsigned int` will be 16 bits wide. Use `uint16_t` instead.

When you say "list", do you mean an array or a linked list? It almost certainly makes more sense to use an array than to use a linked list. It will lead to much better memory utilization, and will enable random access to individual words/bits.

If you need your "long list" to grow dynamically, it might make sense to consider a two-level structure, such as a growing array (or linked list) of pointers to fixed-size **arrays** of `uint16_t`.

Lastly, given that most modern machines are 32- or 64-bit, it may be more efficient to use either 32- or 64-bit words for this.

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify. I was actually looking at a linked list because I will only be reading/writing sequentially. However, memory is most crucial, so I will switch to arrays. Thanks for the `uint16_t` tip as well.

Answer (score 2):

That's assuming there are 16 bits in an `unsigned int`. That cannot actually be guaranted, plus in most systems nowadays it would be at least 32. You can do `sizeof( int ) * CHAR_BITS` to get the number of bits in an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the size of unsigned int or use uint16_t defined in the cstdint. Also using an array instead of a list will be faster since you eliminate the lookup. Ideally you should get the right integer in constant time.